# Is there a sentence $\phi$ that is entailed by all sentences with the same properties as $\phi$? Does $\phi$ entail all of these sentences?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm in an introductory logic class, and I have both of these problems.

1. Is there a sentence $\phi$ with the following properties? If so, what is it? If not, why?

   - $\phi$ together with Fa entails Fb
   - $\phi$ is entailed by all the sentences that, together with Fa, entail Fb
2. Is there a sentence $\phi$ with the following properties? If so, what is it? If not, why?

   - $\phi$ together with Fa entails Fb
   - $\phi$ entails all the sentences that, together with Fa, entail Fb.

For (1), I've reached the conclusion that we want to see if $\phi$ can be derived from all the sentences $\psi$ in the set $\Gamma$ of sentences that, together with Fa, entail Fb.

For (2), I've reached the conclusion that we want to see if every $\psi$ can be derived from one $\phi$.

I reached these conclusions by noting that, by Completeness theorem and Soundness theorem, a sentence is a logical consequence of a set of premises if and only if it is derivable from those premises.

However, I am totally lost on how to prove if my conclusions can be satisfied. On one hand, I feel like the sentence $Fa \rightarrow Fb$ *should* be able to derive all other satisfactory sentences and vice versa. But on the other hand, the juxtaposition of these two problems leads me to believe that only *one* of them has a satisfactory sentence $\phi$, and I have no clue how I would determine such a thing if that is the case.

Comment: What are $Fa$ and $Fb$?

Answer (score 1):

For 1, you can indeed take $Fa \to Fb$:

1. Together with $Fa$, it implies $Fb$
2. It is entailed by any $\psi$ that, together with $Fa$ implies $Fb$

Proof: take any such a $\psi$ and any interpretation that sets $\psi$ to true. Now, if this interpretation does not set $Fa \to Fb$ to True, then that means that it sets $Fa$ to True but $Fb$ to false. So, this interpretation would set $\psi$ and $Fa$ to True but $Fb$ to False, which contradicts that $\psi$ together with $Fa$ implies $Fb$. So, any interpretation that sets any such $\psi$ to True must also set $Fa \to Fb$ to True.

For 2, you can simply take $\bot$: this statement by itself implies everything, and so will:

1. Together with $Fa$ imply $Fb$ ... because $\bot$ implies $Fb$
2. Imply any $\psi$ for which it is true that $\psi$ and $Fa$ together imply $Fb$ ... because $\bot$ implies *any* $\psi$